# I need get a substring in Shell Script

Tags: linux, string, shell

i need help.

I need get a substring in the next line

```
11:46:24.851239 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 11289, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 229)
```

the result must be: `ttl 128`

I hope you can help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
echo '11:46:24.851239 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 11289, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 229)' |
grep -oP "\bttl\s+\d+\b"
ttl 128
```

### NOTE

- `\b` is a word boundary
- `\s` is a space
- `+` mean at least one or more preceding character
- `-P` switch is pcre advanced useful syntax for `grep`
- `-o` switch mean to print only the matching part

### EDIT

If you want to put this in a variable :

```
var=$(
    echo '11:46:24.851239 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 11289, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 229)' |
        grep -oP "\bttl\s+\d+\b"
)
echo "$var"
```

Comment: @cdhowie then upvote yours as consolation. of course +1 for this answer too.

Comment: Can i do this: 

var= ttl

echo '11:46:24.851239 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 11289, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 229)' | grep -oP "\b$var\s+\d+\b"

Answer (score 2):

Try using `grep -o 'ttl [0-9]\+'`:

```
$ echo '11:46:24.851239 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 11289, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 229)' | grep -o 'ttl [0-9]\+'
ttl 128
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed 's/.*[ ]*\(ttl[ ]*[0-9]*\).*/\1/' input
```